# Hangman - hide String and then unhide each char if guessed correct

Tags: java

First off all, I'm not asking for the code... I've just come to the point where I have no idea how to progress... Can someone please explain to me how to begin this step of hangman? I've already got an array of buttons:

```
String  b[]={"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
for(i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i] = new JButton(b[i]);        
    panel.add(buttons[i]);
}
```

And then the word I'm trying to hide comes from a list:

```
public String readWord() {
  try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Words.txt"));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(line != null) {
      String[] wordsLine = line.split(" ");
      boolean addAll = words.addAll(Arrays.asList(wordsLine));
      line = reader.readLine();
    }
    Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String randomWord = words.get(rand.nextInt(words.size()));
    return randomWord;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Now can someone please point me to the right direction to hide the word with "-". And when the user clicks on a correct button, the letter must appear...

I apologize if it isn't as clear as it has be.

Answer (score 7):

Simply use an object to solve this situation:

```
public class HangmanWord {

    private static final char HIDECHAR = '_';

    private String original;     
    private String hidden;  

    public HangmanWord(String original) {
        this.original = original;
        this.hidden = this.createHidden();
    }

    private String createHidden() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.original.length; i++) {
            sb.append(HIDECHAR);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public boolean check(char input) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.original.length; i++) {
            if (this.original[i].equals(input)) {
                found = true;
                this.hidden[i] = this.original[i];
            }
        }
        return found;
    }

    //getter and setter
}
```

When clicking a button you check whether the original word contains your letter. Then you turn the character visible in the hidden word. `hidden[i] = original[i]`.
With this encapsulation the solution should be clearer I hope.

Possible use:

```
public class TestClass() {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String secret = "stackoverflow";
        int wrongGuesses = 0;
        HangmanWord hngm = new HangmanWord(secret);
        System.out.println(hngm.getHidden()); // _____________
        if (hngm.check('a')) {
            System.out.println(hngm.getHidden()); // __a_________
        }
        else {
           wrongGuesses++;
        }
        //... and so on...
    }
}
```

If you need help understanding this just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Keep 2 copies of the string, the word and the obfuscated one (the one containing '-') (preferably as char array or string builder). When a user guesses a letter, search the non-obfuscated version for all instances of that letter. each time you find a match, change the '-' at that index in the obfuscated string to the correct letter.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually not sure if i am getting this problem right, but if your problem is to replace the one field in the String where the pressed Letter needs to be, i would at the Beginning create two Strings, the Original Word, and one (called "Hidden String" in the following) as long as the original Word, consitsting only of "_"s.
Then you need some logic to check if and if so where the pressed letter is in the word (that should not be hard, using StringBuilder) and afterwards chaning the appropriate Field in the "Hidden String" to the letter. To show the character on your GUI (i assume you have one, since you have buttons) on which you use some sort of TextField/-View for showing the "Hidden String", i would just delete the previous Content of the TextField, and write out the new "Hidden String".

Hope that helps...

EDIT: actually saving two char-Arrays instead of two Strings would be much more elegant, and can also easily be converted to a string to be written out.