# Hangman masking string, unhiding character

Tags: java

I'm writing a hangman application and I'm at the point where I have to write the code to Hide each char in the string (the word being guessed) with "-"... And I've posted a lot of questions on hoe to do it and one of my replies was:[Hangman - hide String and then unhide each char if guessed correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073860/hangman-hide-string-and-then-unhide-each-char-if-guessed-correct)

```
public class HangmanWord {

private static final char HIDECHAR = '_';

private String original;     
private String hidden;  

public HangmanWord(String original) {
    this.original = original;
    this.hidden = this.createHidden();
}

private String createHidden() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < this.original.length; i++) {
        sb.append(HIDECHAR);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public boolean check(char input) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.original.length; i++) {
        if (this.original[i].equals(input)) {
            found = true;
            this.hidden[i] = this.original[i];
        }
    }
    return found;
}

//getter and setter
}
```

---

```
public class TestClass() {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String secret = "stackoverflow";
    int wrongGuesses = 0;
    HangmanWord hngm = new HangmanWord(secret);
    System.out.println(hngm.getHidden()); // _____________
    if (hngm.check('a')) {
        System.out.println(hngm.getHidden()); // __a_________
    }
    else {
       wrongGuesses++;
    }
    //... and so on...
}
}
```

I tried to use this code with mine and I had a lot of errors and conclusion it didn't work with my code. In my code i've created an array buttons where if the person clicks on a button I get an message saying if the letter is in the word or not... Now I want to replace this code with where it doesn't give me an message but unhides the char and if there's no char it has to change the image

If possible can anyone explain why it didn't work with my code or can anyone please explain to me what to do...

my button array:

```
public JButton getButton(final String text){
   final JButton button = new JButton(text);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
             if(original.toUpperCase().indexOf(button.getText())!=-1){
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your word does contain " + text       );
             }
             else{
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is no " + text );
                 error++;
                    if(error >= 0) imageName = "hangman1.jpg";
                    if(error >= 1) imageName = "hangman2.jpg";
                    if(error >= 2) imageName = "hangman3.jpg";
                    if(error >= 3) imageName = "hangman4.jpg";
                    if(error >= 4) imageName = "hangman5.jpg";
                    if(error >= 5) imageName = "hangman6.jpg";
                    if(error >= 7) imageName = "hangman7.jpg"; 
             }
             }
             });
             return button;
}
```

my full code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.List;

public final class Hangman extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
String original = readWord();
int error;
String imageName;

JButton btnAddWord = new JButton("Add New Word");
JButton btnRestart = new JButton("Restart");
JButton btnHelp = new JButton("Help");
JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");

JLabel word = new JLabel(original);

static JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
static JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
static JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
static JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();

public Hangman(){
    Container content =getContentPane();
    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

   btnAddWord.addActionListener(this);
   btnRestart.addActionListener(this);
   btnHelp.addActionListener(this);
   btnExit.addActionListener(this);

   ImageIcon icon = null;
   if(imageName != null){
   icon = new ImageIcon(imageName);
                    }
  JLabel image = new JLabel();
  image.setIcon(icon);
  panel2.add(image);

   panel3.add(word);
   panel4.add(btnAddWord);
   panel4.add(btnRestart);
   panel4.add(btnHelp);
   panel4.add(btnExit);

    for(char i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++){
        String buttonText = new Character(i).toString();
        JButton button = getButton(buttonText);
        panel1.add(button);
    }
}

public JButton getButton(final String text){
   final JButton button = new JButton(text);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
             if(original.toUpperCase().indexOf(button.getText())!=-1){
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your word does contain " + text     );
             }
             else{
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is no " + text );
                 error++;
                    if(error >= 0) imageName = "hangman1.jpg";
                    if(error >= 1) imageName = "hangman2.jpg";
                    if(error >= 2) imageName = "hangman3.jpg";
                    if(error >= 3) imageName = "hangman4.jpg";
                    if(error >= 4) imageName = "hangman5.jpg";
                    if(error >= 5) imageName = "hangman6.jpg";
                    if(error >= 7) imageName = "hangman7.jpg"; 
             }
             }
             });
             return button;
}
public String readWord(){
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Words.txt"));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(line != null){
            String[] wordsLine = line.split(" ");
            boolean addAll = words.addAll(Arrays.asList(wordsLine));
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        String randomWord = words.get(rand.nextInt(words.size()));
        return randomWord;

}catch (Exception e){
    return null;
}
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource() == btnAddWord){
        try{
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Words.txt", true);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw, true);

            String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a word: ");

            pw.println(word);
            pw.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ie){
            System.out.println("Error Thrown" + ie.getMessage());
        }
    }
    if(e.getSource() == btnRestart){

    }
    if(e.getSource() == btnHelp){
        String message = "The word to guess is represented by a row of dashes, giving the number of letters and category of the word."
               + "\nIf the guessing player suggests a letter which occurs in the word, the other player writes it in all its correct positions."
               + "\nIf the suggested letter does not occur in the word, the other player draws one element of the hangman diagram as a tally mark."
               + "\n"
               + "\nThe game is over when:"
               + "\nThe guessing player completes the word, or guesses the whole word correctly"
               + "\nThe other player completes the diagram";
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,message, "Help",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    if(e.getSource() == btnExit){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public static void main (String [] args){
    Hangman frame = new Hangman();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 600);
    frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(panel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.add(panel4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've had a good start with your code, but first you need to get the design clear in your mind, *before* writing code. Let's think about it, in steps:

- When the application is launched, you load all the words in the file. So that's a step that is performed only once, and its result (the words in the file) should be saved.
- The previous step does not seem to be related to your GUI code, so you may want to do it in your `main` method, and then pass the results to your GUI class. You can even extract this functionality into a separate class, along with choosing a random word.
- Once the GUI is shown, you show a label symbolizing the hidden word. The text of this label should contain as many hidden characters (`'-'`) as the word's characters.
- Whenever a correct button is pressed, all matching characters in the word should be shown.
- Whenever a wrong button is pressed, an error counter is incremented and an image is shown.
- When the whole word is uncovered, character buttons should be disabled.

This leads to a design where you have a separate helper class with a method for reading the words file and another for choosing a random word. Possibly something along the lines of this:

```
class WordsReader {
    public String[] readWords(String filename) {
        // ...
    }

    public String chooseWord(String[] words) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Once a new word is chosen, you should update the label. This is where the `HangmanWord` class suggested above comes in handy. It stores both the original word and its hidden representation. This allows you to call the `check` method in the buttons' handler, and update the label's text with the updated hidden representation. The rest of your code should work fine, although it can still be improved.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the chars of the string, and replace the guessed letters with '-' in a new string, and display that (while behind the scenes you still have the full one)

```
public [static] String hideString(String string, int[] guessedLetterIndices) {
    char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
    for(int index : guessedLetterIndices)
        chars[i] = '-';//Replace this with any letter
    for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        char c = '-';
        for(int index : guessedLetterIndices)
            if(index == i)
                c = chars[i];
        chars[i] = c;
    }

    return new String(chars);
}
```

or if you currently have an array of chars that they have chosen, as opposed to indices of characters...

```
public [static] String hideString(String string, char[] guessedLetters) {
    char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
    char[] hidden = (string.replaceAll("(.|\n)", "-").toCharArray();
    for(int i=0;i<chars.length;i++) {
        for(char c : guessedLetters)
            if(chars[i] == c) {
                hidden[i] = chars[i];
                break;
            }
    ]
    return new String(chars);
}
```

That's what I'd do. As far as why yours does not work, could you tell me the errors you're getting? Make sure you're importing StringBuilder and stuff (whatever else they use)

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense, as far as I understand your code replaces the letter with "-" and I want the exact oppiside where the code is hidden with "-" and the when the user guessed the correct letter, the char unhides... like i said as far as I understand so please correct me if im wrong... and yeah I wish I could give you my errors but I've restarted this code over and over again and i've tried to fuse this persons code with mine weeks ago

Comment: @user1614977 Alright, sorry, I was being stupid and did the opposite of hangman, lol, fixed now, haven't tested either though, so try em both and see if one works :)