# StringBuffer hangman

Tags: java

In my hangman application I want to hide a word that's suppose to be guessed, with "_" and I finally found a site where someone explains on how to do that but when I fused his code with mine I seem to get errors when I run it...

This is the site where I found the code

http://www.jcreator.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=7761

and this is how I tried to use his code

```
StringBuffer original = new StringBuffer(readWord());
StringBuffer secret = new StringBuffer(hideWord()) ;
StringBuffer hidden;
```

---

```
 public StringBuffer hideWord(){
    for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++){
        hidden.append("_ ");
    }
    hidden.deleteCharAt(hidden.length()-1);
    return hidden;
}
```

---

```
 public JButton getButton(final String text){
   final JButton button = new JButton(text);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
             String s = button.getText();
             int index = original.indexOf(s);
             if(index != -1){
                 hidden.deleteCharAt(index*2);
                 hidden.insert(index *2, s);
             }
             else{
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is no " + text );
                 error++;
                    if(error >= 0) imageName = "hangman1.jpg";
                    if(error >= 1) imageName = "hangman2.jpg";
                    if(error >= 2) imageName = "hangman3.jpg";
                    if(error >= 3) imageName = "hangman4.jpg";
                    if(error >= 4) imageName = "hangman5.jpg";
                    if(error >= 5) imageName = "hangman6.jpg";
                    if(error >= 7) imageName = "hangman7.jpg"; 
             }
             }
             });
             return button;
}
```

and seem to get an problem with my JLabel when displaying the word so I changed it .toString

```
JLabel word = new JLabel(secret.toString());
```

can someone please tell me wy my app doesn't want to run and if the way i fused the code is correct?

Comment: `"but when I fused his code with mine I seem to get errors when I run it..."`: the problem may be your trying to "fuse" the code as that often leads to disaster. Don't do that. Instead, use the ideas gained from the other code and write all your own code but using those ideas.

Comment: Perhaps this is a continuation of your [previous thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205223/hangman-masking-string-unhiding-character)?

Comment: And saying you have "a problem" doesn't really help diagnose anything. What happened? What's different between that and what's supposed to happen? How have you tried to resolve the situation? Etc.

Comment: well I seem to have an problem displaying the hidden word in my JLabel

Answer (score 3):

`StringBuffer` is not a `String`.

When you are calling `new JLabel(secret)` you're asking the compiler to find a constructor of `JLabel` which takes a `StringBuffer` as a parameter, which there aren't any.

As HovercraftFullOfEels states, before implementing anybody else's ideas, understand what those ideas are and how they work, not only well you get better results, you'll become a better developer ;)

Comment: okay I understand that a stringbuffer is not a string, but sofar it looks like the only way ill be able to hide an string with _ it using a bufferstring to delete and then insert the correct letter gussed... Now possible to display a stringbuffer then?

Comment: Well, your solution worked didn't it?  `StringBuffer.toString()` will convert the `StringBuffer`'s internal buffer to `String` object?  `StringBuffer` is a good choice to use if you want to do lots of modifications to a string of characters as it doesn't have the memory issues associated with manipulating a `String`. The other idea I had was using a `JLabel` for each character. You can set up a nice icon when the guess is used (successfully or otherwise), while having a "_" for the remaining guess. Just an idea